# Convert array to comma separated list in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell. Please correct me if anything I say doesn't make sense.

I am trying to convert an array in PowerShell to a comma separated list.

This is what I have stored in $iplist

```
IP
--
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

When I run `$iplist -join ','` my output is:

```
,,
```

So I created a test array, `$iplistest = @("192.168.1.2","192.168.1.3","192.168.1.4")` which is as follows:

```
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
```

When I run `$iplisttest -join ','` it works:

```
192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.4
```

I am assuming my issue is the header in the $iplist array, "IP". How do I delete a header from an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to "delete the head". you can select it by running

```
$iplist.IP -join ','
```

Comment: Works perfect, thanks! Say I did want to delete the header (if that is the correct terminology); is that possible?

Comment: If you want to delete the header, run `$iplist | select -expand IP`